# Start new python interpreter from different python interpreter

Tags: python, import, subprocess, abaqus, sys.path

From a python 2.7.3 interpreter (abaqus python) I am trying to start a python 2.7.14 interpreter and let it carry out a script. So in 2.7.3 I am using the following code to do so:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('"C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\python" my_script.py')
```

I am working on Windows and have also tried:

```
import os
os.system('start cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\python" my_script.py"')
```

My Problem is, that the sys.path variable in the new 2.7.14 interpreter is extending the sys.path variable from the 2.7.3 interpreter. Both paths to the site-packages are present. Therefore I am not able to import the correct matplotlib module. Does anyone have a clue how it is possible to get the sys.path corresponding to each interpreter? Thank you in advance.

Comment: does that work when you're running `"C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\python" my_script.py` from a terminal (not in python system cmd)

Comment: Yes it does. I have also checked the parents process id and they both differ. Also if I start to cmd individually and a different python version in each the sys.path differs as desired.

Comment: `sys.path` doesn't propagate through different python processes, no way. But if you manually set `PYTHONPATH` from the first interpreter, that would explain a lot.

Comment: The `PYTHONPATH` is untouched in the whole procedure.

Comment: can you print 1) the `sys.path` variable in the parent python process, 2) `sys.path` in the child python process and 3) the value of `PYTHONPATH` and [edit] that in your question?